# Ubuntu 17.10 cannot play videos

Tags: drivers, graphics, video, 17.10, gpu-driver

After upgrading to Ubuntu 17.10 all videos including local, youtube videos and dailymotion videos show as still images only, I reinstalled ubuntu restricted exrtas and addons also I reinstalled libtotem to no avail.

I have Dell Inspiron 3521

I have an AMD graphics card

This may help:

```
lspci -nn | grep VGA

00:02.0 VGA compatible controller [0300]: Intel Corporation 3rd Gen Core processor Graphics Controller [8086:0166] (rev 09)
01:00.0 VGA compatible controller [0300]: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD/ATI] Thames [Radeon HD 7500M/7600M Series] [1002:6840] (rev ff)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Some more details are needed.
Since Ubuntu 16.04, the fglrx package which contains the proprietary drivers, is no longer available.
Were you using that? you can check by doing something like:

```
dmesg | grep -i ati
```

If not, it might be an upgrade issue, which you could rule out by doing a fresh install (if that is acceptable).
If the open source driver is used and you are sure you have no manual configuration changes, you can file a bug report on launchpad:
https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu

Make sure to follow the guidelines (search first for existing ones etc).

You could try the proprietary driver from here too:
http://support.amd.com/en-us/download/desktop/previous/detail?os=Ubuntu%20x86%2064&rev=15.9
but it may not work because it doesn't support 17.10 officially.

More info on the open source driver can be found here:
https://help.ubuntu.com/community/RadeonDriver
(that will probably give you enough info to get to a solution).
Good luck and please post how it goes!

Comment: Thanks for your quick reply it seems that I will need a fresh installation